# Does adding a key value pair to a dictionary change the pointer's address?

Tags: swift

So I am working on a piece of code on IOS Swift, Xcode 6.2, and am trying to trace why changes in a dictionary do not perpetuate up callbacks. I started by printing the address of the dictionary along the way to see where the address changes, and I found the following lines of code to be the part where the

```
println("Address of grouped asset in 811 is " + EtaError.pointerToString(assetGroup!))
assetGroup![groupDid!] = Array<Asset>();
println("Address of grouped asset in 813 is " + EtaError.pointerToString(assetGroup!))
```

Note: asset group is a string->Asset array dictionary and EtaError.pointerToString is a function that returns the address of the given pointer, which is a separate function I have written.

Is assigning a new key-value pair supposed to change the address of a pointer to the dictionary?

Comment: You want to know if adding an item to a dictionary changes the location of the dictionary in memory?

Comment: I'm ok with it changing the location of the dictionary in memory, however the class from which I call this function to update a key-value pair does not reflect the change in the dictionary even after using the keyword inout to pass the dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionaries in Swift are value, not reference, type like `NSDictionary`. Updates to the copy won't be reflected in the original. Here's a minimal example:

```
var a = ["name": "John", "location": "Chicago"]
var b = a

b["title"] = "developer"

print(a) // a does not contain the 'title' key
print(b)
```

You need to update the original after updating the copy. You can delve into stuffs like `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>` but it's a dark road down there.

Comment: Quoting from Apple's swift documentation,

"You write an in-out parameter by placing the inout keyword at the start of its parameter definition. An in-out parameter has a value that is passed in to the function, is modified by the function, and is passed back out of the function to replace the original value."

If I use the same, it should pass the value of the dictionary as a reference right? It is still not correctly updating the original pointer even after using inout

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html

Answer (score 0):

### Value Semantics of `Dictionary`

From your comment:

> however the class from which I call this function to update a key-value pair does not reflect the change in

The updates to dictionaries won't be reflected in other parts of your code. **`Dictionary` is a value type in Swift, which means it is copied upon every assignment, and each part of your code has its private copy of the value**.

The change of the address is also interesting however.

### Why is the `Dictionary`'s address changing?

The address changes because the underlying data structure of the `Dictionary` needs to be resized when you add values.

You can test it with the following simple code in a playground:

```
var dict = ["a":"b"]
print(unsafeAddressOf(dict))
// 0x00007ffc216278d0

dict["a"] = "c"    
print(unsafeAddressOf(dict))
// address remains: 0x00007ffc216278d0

dict["b"] = "f"
print(unsafeAddressOf(dict))
// new address: 0x00007ffc21705f40

dict["c"] = "f"
print(unsafeAddressOf(dict))
// address remains: 0x00007ffc21705f40

dict["d"] = "f"
print(unsafeAddressOf(dict))
// new address: 0x00007ffc21626db0

...
```

You will see that an address change will only occur when you add key/ value pairs, not when you modify an existing key.

**Swift doubles the capacity of the dictionary upon copy, therefore, after the first copy, you can add two more values before the dictionary is copied again.**

From the documentation:

> The actual capacity will be the smallest power of 2 that's >= minimumCapacity.

If you initialize the dictionary with a sufficient capacity you will see that it won't be copied when you add values:

```
var dict = [String:String](minimumCapacity: 20)
```